# Visualizing Drake collision geometries in Meshcat

Tags: drake

I'm using the Python bindings for the Drake robotics package. Is there any way to set up my Drake script so that I can have a checkbox in Meshcat to visualize my collision geometries?

Comment: In your python script, what are you doing to visualize? E.g., are you calling something like ApplyVisualizationConfig()? Are you instantiating a `MeshcatVisualizer` on your own? If you do the former, there's a flag that says `publish_proximity` that defaults to `true`. So, using `ApplyVisualizationConfig()` should get you "proximity" (aka collision) geometries for free.

Comment: I copied and pasted the general outline from Prof Tedrake's Manipulation lecture codes which has the line `meshcat = StartMeshcat()` and then later `visualizer = MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pydrake.visualization.ApplyVisualizationConfig(config=..., builder=..., meshcat=...)](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.visualization.html#pydrake.visualization.ApplyVisualizationConfig) to add Meshcat visualization to your Diagram.  That will add several checkboxes, sliders, etc. to Meshcat to control what is visualized, including a checkbox for the proximity geometry.

Comment: Thanks @jwnimmer-tri. I got it working. Is there an option to publish coordinate frames?

Comment: I published this as a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76683262/how-do-i-visualize-coordinate-frames-in-drake-using-meshcat

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @jwnimmer-tri's answer, I used the following code (after importing the necessary names from `pydrake.all`.

```
visualizer = MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
visualization_config = VisualizationConfig()
visualization_config.publish_contacts = True
visualization_config.publish_proximity = True
ApplyVisualizationConfig(visualization_config, builder, meshcat=meshcat)
```

The controls appeared under the Drake menu in meshcat.
[image]

Comment: Calling `ApplyVisualizationConfig()` the way you have should make the initial definition of `visualizer` at best redundant. Possibly harmful. Unless you are explicitly using `visualizer` to manipulate the `MeshcatVisualizer` you should simply eliminate the line. If you *are* using `visualizer`, then you'll need to pull it out of the `builder` (or resulting diagram after `Build()`) to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks @SeanCurtis. Would you provide a snippet that gets me the visualizer out of a builder or diagram? I actually am using the visualizer object to do `.StartRecording()`

Comment: Looking at my diagram, I see actually three internal visualizers called `meshcat_visualizer(proximity)`, `meshcat_visualizer(illustration)` and `meshcat_contact_visualizer`. Is it proper to call `.StartRecording()` on all three of these?

Comment: Doing some digging, I see that the visualizer's `[Start|Stop|Publish]Recording()` simply calls down to the underlying meshcat object. So now I'm doing `meshcat.StartRecording()` instead of `visualizer.StartRecording()` and it seems to work. Please let me know if this is the Drake-approved way to do it :)

Comment: Absolutely! If that works, you're done. There's a vague part of the back of my mind that believes that not everything is going to be included in the animation as you might hope. But, I believe that what *can* be in recorded, will be recorded that way.